# Error parsing ... ParsedContract.sol:33:18: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin, truffle-compile

When compiling my contract code in truffle I receive this error:

> Error parsing
>   zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol:
>   ParsedContract.sol:33:18: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got
>   'LParen'
>       emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

I am running through this guide: https://maksimivanov.com/posts/ethereum-react-dapp-tutorial

I download zeppelin-solidity's files, and copied and paste the code. I don't understand why this wouldn't be working. I tried changing the pragma to 4.21 because that is what the standardToken's solidity code is written in. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What version of truffle are you using? Try updating to the latest that requires solc 0.4.23.

Comment: It was 4.1.3, updated to 4.1.8 and it fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to truffle 4.1.8 and this fixed my issue immediately. I thought I had updated, but I didn't update truffle globally.